# VUE v-tab route changes URL but doesnt update content of tab

Tags: vue.js, tabs, router, vuetify.js

v-tab routes update url but doesnt load v-tab-item content
Tabs are changing together with url but content of the tab doesnt appear

```
<v-tabs>
    <v-tab key="item1" :to="{name: title, params: {title: 'A'}}">
        item1
    </v-tab>

    <v-tab key="item2" :to="{name: title, params: {title: 'B'}}">
        item2
    </v-tab>

    <v-tab-item accesskey="item1">
        Item 1 description .... 
    </v-tab-item>

    <v-tab-item accesskey="item2">
        Item 2 description .... 
    </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>

<router-view></router-view>
```

Comment: Do you change `title` param only?

Comment: yes I change only title param